# What's the purpose of the formdata event when handling form submit with javascript?

Tags: javascript, form-submit

Usually I use this pattern to handle a form submit with javascript:

```
form.onsubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fd = new FormData(form);
    const res = await fetch(url, {body: fd});
    //...
};
```

But I've also seen this pattern (e.g. in the MDN docs):

```
form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    new FormData(form);
};

form.onformdata = async (e) => {
    const fd = e.formData;
    const res = await fetch(url, {body: fd});
};
```

What is the prupose/advantage of using the formdata event?

Answer (score 1):

Advantage could be that you don't need to wait while your form will be parsed to the FormData instance(expessially when you have a huge form) but disadvantage is that it's not fully supported by browsers.
[As you can see here.](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_globaleventhandlers_onformdata)